# Getting average packet latency ,flit latency in the range of thousands in stats.txt file when doing the simulation in garnet (gem5)

Tags: gem5

I downloaded gem5 from gem5.org using the command
git clone https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5
I build  using scons command
sudo scons build/NULL/gem5.opt PROTOCOL=Garnet_standalone -j 9
I simulated the network with the configuration
./build/NULL/gem5.opt  configs/example/garnet_synth_traffic.py  --num-cpus=64 --num-dirs=64 --network=garnet --topology=Mesh_XY --mesh-rows=8 --synthetic=tornado --routing-algorithm=1 --sim-cycles=10000 --injectionrate=0.1

Then i am getting packet latency value in the range of thousands(7000)...Is it correct
if i give injection rate less than .1 then i am getting nan(Not a number) as packet latency value
My friends doing with same configuration they all are getting values like15,17....

Can u tell what is the mistake i had done...I didnt change any code ..only done the simulation..

Answer (score 1):

I had previously used an older repo, which gave values of latency in the range of 10-15. After downloading the latest repo, I also got the values to be in thousands.

After reading the code in `NetworkInterface.cc::incrementStats()`, we can easily spot the change that in the older repo the latency is collected in 'Cycles', whereas in the newer repo, it is collected in 'Ticks'.
As far as I know, 1 Cycle = 500 Ticks (but I need to confirm that).

Thus, the values we are getting by the new repo are correct, only that they are in ticks.